# Visual Studio navigation bar stops populating with certain TypeScript files

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript

At some point through my app's life, not sure when, the navigation bar stopped populating. I don't see anything output to the JavaScript language service or anywhere else that indicates why. <kbd>F12</kbd> jumps to definitions just as it did before and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>**,** <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>**,** <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> toggle method collapsing as expected.

What might be causing this issue? Any way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an issue in 0.8.3 / 0.8.3.1 where the navigation bar doesn't work if you're in an external module (i.e. a file with a top-level `export` or `import`).

Comment: Is this something that might be fixed in 0.8.x or not until 0.9.x?

Comment: There won't be any more 0.8.x releases.